# iPhone: Where to Start Learning OpenGL ES for basic 2D drawing?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

All I want is really absolutely basic 2D drawing stuff e.g. rectangles, circles, paths, curves, béziers and so on. I don't need all the 3D model meshes with all this texturing and lighting. Is there a good learning resource for a fast startup programming just for fun?

Comment: OpenGL is not the easiest way to learn 2D drawing. It doesn't even draw circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Hetal: Get an OpenGL book.
But if you don't like that advice check this one out on amazon. It might help you start game programming on the iPhone. It also has links to other books that you can also purchase on amazon.
[http://www.amazon.com/OpenGL-ES-Game-Development/dp/1592003702](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592003702)

One other option is to of course use google to look for OpenGL ES tutorials such as this one: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html

Answer (score 3):

The Red book for Open GL is a good starting point to learn Open GL. You can get it online. Just google.

Comment: why google? gonna use bing. thanks ;) maybe there's also a "better" "starting point" rather than jumping into the deep water? i mean something that points out openGL ES on the iphone.

Answer (score 2):

Also don’t skip [Jeff LaMarche’s](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/search/label/OpenGL%20ES?updated-max=2010-04-27T14%3A49%3A00-07%3A00&max-results=20) Tutorial on OpenGL ES for the iPhone.